# onCreateLoader() only called one time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I've a fragment that extends ListFragment and implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. Inside this fragment i have a button that should call a webservice and fill the List.

The problem is this method that only is called once, only when the fragment is created, and it would me be called every time that i press the button:

```
@Override
public Loader<List<ResultSearchUser>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new SearchUsersTask(getActivity(), page, size);
}
```

Here is my button:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
    Button buttonSearchUsers = (Button) mLinearLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.buttonSearchUsers);
    buttonSearchUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (user.getInterests() != null
                    && user.getInterests().size() > 0) {
                page++;
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, SearchFragment.this);
            } 
        }
    });
   ....
```

Why onCreatedLoader() is only called when the fragment is created? And why the method onLoadFinished() is called everytime that i press the button?  What is the correct way to call my Task and fill the List using the method onLoadFinished()?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html):

> Ensures a loader is initialized and active. If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. Otherwise the last created loader is re-used.

In other words, `initLoader()` will only trigger a call to `onCreateLoader()` when the `Loader` isn't already created. On subsequent calls, the `Loader` will be reused.

If you need to forcefully destroy/create an existing `Loader`, you should call `LoaderManager#restartLoader()` instead.

Comment: Got it. So what is the best practice for it? Switch my button to call my Task and use a callback to fill ListFragment? Put "getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, SearchFragment.this);" on button.setOnClickListener() sounds like a (bad) work around.

Comment: If all you want to do is re-execute the `Loader`s load task, then you can call `Loader#forceLoad()`.